# Bootstrap light box, with next arrows not aligned

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

for one of the web sites that i am developing i have used the bootstrap light box, along with the next and back buttons. so from the slider when an video or image is clicked it will be displayed in the light box, and there the next buttons will help to navigates. while navigating the arrow that is suppose to be in the middle suddenly moves to the top. how can this be prevented from moving?
[image: this is how the arrow should appear]
[image: but when sliding suddenly the arrow goes up ad in this picture.]

the java script code for the light box

```
EkkoLightbox.prototype = {
    modal_shown: function() {
      var video_id,
        _this = this;
      if (!this.options.remote) {
        return this.error('No remote target given');
      } else {
        this.gallery = this.$element.data('gallery');
        if (this.gallery) {
          if (this.options.gallery_parent_selector === 'document.body' || this.options.gallery_parent_selector === '') {
            this.gallery_items = $(document.body).find('*[data-toggle="lightbox"][data-gallery="' + this.gallery + '"]');
          } else {
            this.gallery_items = this.$element.parents(this.options.gallery_parent_selector).first().find('*[data-toggle="lightbox"][data-gallery="' + this.gallery + '"]');
          }
          this.gallery_index = this.gallery_items.index(this.$element);
          $(document).on('keydown.ekkoLightbox', this.navigate.bind(this));
          if (this.options.directional_arrows && this.gallery_items.length > 1) {
            this.lightbox_container.append('<div class="ekko-lightbox-nav-overlay"><a href="#" class="' + this.strip_stops(this.options.left_arrow_class) + '"></a><a href="#" class="' + this.strip_stops(this.options.right_arrow_class) + '"></a></div>');
            this.modal_arrows = this.lightbox_container.find('div.ekko-lightbox-nav-overlay').first();
            this.lightbox_container.find('a' + this.strip_spaces(this.options.left_arrow_class)).on('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              return _this.navigate_left();
            });
            this.lightbox_container.find('a' + this.strip_spaces(this.options.right_arrow_class)).on('click', function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              return _this.navigate_right();
            });
          }
        }
        if (this.options.type) {
          if (this.options.type === 'image') {
            return this.preloadImage(this.options.remote, true);
          } else if (this.options.type === 'youtube' && (video_id = this.getYoutubeId(this.options.remote))) {
            return this.showYoutubeVideo(video_id);
          } else if (this.options.type === 'vimeo') {
            return this.showVimeoVideo(this.options.remote);
          } else if (this.options.type === 'instagram') {
            return this.showInstagramVideo(this.options.remote);
          } else if (this.options.type === 'url') {
            return this.loadRemoteContent(this.options.remote);
          } else if (this.options.type === 'video') {
            return this.showVideoIframe(this.options.remote);
          } else {
            return this.error("Could not detect remote target type. Force the type using data-type=\"image|youtube|vimeo|instagram|url|video\"");
          }
        } else {
          return this.detectRemoteType(this.options.remote);
        }
      }
    },
    strip_stops: function(str) {
      return str.replace(/\./g, '');
    },
    strip_spaces: function(str) {
      return str.replace(/\s/g, '');
    },
    isImage: function(str) {
      return str.match(/(^data:image\/.*,)|(\.(jp(e|g|eg)|gif|png|bmp|webp|svg)((\?|#).*)?$)/i);
    },
    isSwf: function(str) {
      return str.match(/\.(swf)((\?|#).*)?$/i);
    },
    getYoutubeId: function(str) {
      var match;
      match = str.match(/^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/);
      if (match && match[2].length === 11) {
        return match[2];
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    getVimeoId: function(str) {
      if (str.indexOf('vimeo') > 0) {
        return str;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    getInstagramId: function(str) {
      if (str.indexOf('instagram') > 0) {
        return str;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
```

Comment: We'd help you, but without the code we can't!

Comment: please share your codes.

Comment: will the java script code of the light box will be sufficient ?